# Android Cognito push sync

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate cognito with android app for sync the data.
I am following the docs provided by AWS at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/push-sync.html) link

As per this docs there should be a BroadcastReceiver which will receive the push sync.

But I am already using the push notification in my app. And as per [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) there is not mentioned for any broad cast receiver.
All the notifications are received in the  *public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data);* method of *GcmListenerService*.

Can any one help me to clear about the broadcast receiver the [aws push sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/push-sync.html) talking about ?

Comment: Well both listener and receiver serve the same purpose to deliver notifications but there are some basic differences, you can see here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794684/what-is-the-difference-between-a-listener-and-a-receiver-android]

Comment: thanks @Rachit Dhall for response.  Its fine that purpose of both are same but in onReceive there is an "intent" as a parameter and i can use that intent for getting the information like "PushSyncUpdate update = client.getPushSyncUpdate(intent);"   But how it will be possible in the "onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) " method of GcmListenerService. Have you got my problem ?

Comment: I hope the answer below solved the problem. I will work in getting the docs updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `BroadcastReceiver` has been deprecated and AWS have not updated their docs yet. But you can simply create an `Intent` from the supplied data `Bundle` in the `GcmListenerService`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    CognitoSyncManager manager;
    try {
      manager = CognitoSyncClientManager.getInstance();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
      Log.w(TAG, "sync manager is not initialized");
      return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(data);
    PushSyncUpdate update = manager.getPushSyncUpdate(intent);
    //...
```